# How can I ignore final newline char when using (cin.get(c))

Tags: c++

I have a short program that takes a text input and outputs each character including the full escape sequence.

"Stack Overflow 2020" becomes -> "Stack\sOverFlow\s\2\0\2\0"

However, when I run my program I have to use -n flag in the terminal overwise it includes an additional newline character. Can I prevent my program from outputting this additional /n ( newline ) character at the end of my output?

With flag

echo -n "Stack OverFlow 2020" | ./escapec -> Stack\sOverFlow\s\2\0\2\0

Without - See additional newline at end of the output

echo "Stack OverFlow 2020" | ./escapec ->    Stack\sOverFlow\s\2\0\2\0\n

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string escapeChar(char c);

// EscapeMap is used by escapeChar to obtain the un-escaped string of ascii encodings. space,  tab, carriage return and  newline.

map<int, string> escapeMap = {  {32, "\\s"}, {9, "\\t"}, {13, "\\r"}, {92, "\\"},{10,"\\n"} };


string escapeChar(char c) {

        if (isdigit(c)) {
                return "\\" + to_string(int(c) - 48);
        }
        else {
                if (escapeMap.count(int(c))) {
                        return escapeMap.at(int(c));
                }
        }

        return string(1, c);

}

int main() {

        char c;

        while (cin.get(c))
        {
                cout << escapeChar(c);
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? `echo` is meant to write a newline, if you don't use the `-n` flag.

Comment: Is there a straightforward way to ignore the final /n when not using the -n flag

Comment: `(int)c - 48` – are you aware that you can simply calculate `c - '0'`? From sight of C++, `char` is nothing else than an ordinary integral (usually) eight bits large... Similarly in the map, you could have `{ ' ', "\\s"}` in the initialiser as well. Using numeric values only is necessary if you need to process ASCII data (or compatible) and your local machine you compile on uses an incompatible character set (like EBCDIC).

Comment: Why don't you simply check for that character? `while(std::cin.get()) { if(c != '\n') { ... } }` – you'd get all output on the same line, though, so you might just output the character unescaped in the else branch – or perhaps better `std::endl`, as this flushes the output, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `peek` to read the next character without removing it from the stream, then if it is `EOF` and the current character is a newline, then just do a workaround: don't print it:

```cpp
while (cin.get(c)) {
    if (c == '\n' && cin.peek() == EOF) break;
    cout << escapeChar(c);
}
```

Comment: I'm just curious, what does this do if the terminal is unbuffered?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Buffering only applies to output, and buffers are flushed at (normal) program exit (as well as when reading), so buffering shouldn't make any difference with this program.

Comment: So the cin.peek() blocks after you press the enter key until you type another character?